# POST request sending an empty object even though console.log is show input values are being captured

Tags: reactjs, post, jsx

When i submit the form, the object shows up as empty in my db.json file even though console.log is showing that i've capture the inputs.

There are no errors that are popping up, but rather once i hit post, it just shows a new object with an unique ID but nothing that was entered into the form was captured.

```
import React,  { useState } from "react";

const blankNewLegend = {
  name:"",
  image:"",
  nickname:"",
  legendType:"",
  tactAbility:"",
  passAbility:"",
  ultAbility:"",
  season: 0,
  likes: 0,
};


function NewLegendForm() {

  const[newLegend, setNewLegend] = useState(blankNewLegend)

console.log(newLegend)

function handleChange(e){
  console.log(e)
  setNewLegend((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value

      
  }
  ));
  e.preventDefault();

}

function handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log(newLegend)
  
  fetch('http://localhost:6004/legends',{
      method: "POST",
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newLegend),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res, 'this')
    })
    
}



  return (
    <div className="new-legend-form">
      <h2>Add New Legend</h2>
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Legend name" value={newLegend.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image URL" value={newLegend.image} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" value={newLegend.nickname} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="legendType" placeholder="Legend Type" value={newLegend.legendType} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="tactAbility" placeholder="Tactical Ability" value={newLegend.tactAbility} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="passAbility" placeholder="Passive Ability" value={newLegend.passAbility} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="ultAbility" placeholder="Ultimate Ability" value={newLegend.ultAbility} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="number" name="season"  placeholder="Debut Season" value={newLegend.season} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="number" name="likes"  placeholder="Likes" value={newLegend.likes} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Add Legend</button>
      </form>
      <p>{newLegend.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewLegendForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database API can't read the content-type. In your fetch statement, change the key "header" to "headers" (i.e. plural), as shown below.  You should then see the full json object in your db.json file:

```
function handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log(newLegend)
  
  fetch('http://localhost:6004/legends',{
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newLegend),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res, 'this')
    })
```

}